# Using firejail on firefox

Tags: linux, sandbox

I'm using firejail to sandbox Firefox, but doing `/home/me/bin/firejail /home/me/local/bin/Firefox` emits the below:

> execvp: no such file or directory.

Under `strace` there are multiple entries of `setresuid(-1,0,-1) =-1 EPERM  (operation not permitted)`. It seems as if firejail is not able to run suid and access some root permission directories. I've tried shifting binaries into different directories but that does not work. Using system installed binaries of firejail/Firefox, it works.